# Creating a function that will index a word in a string in python

Tags: python

For my assignment, I am asked to create a function that will return the index of a word in a string if the word is in the string, and return (-1) if the word is not in the string

```
bigstring = "I have trouble doing this assignment"
mywords = bigstring.split()
def FindIndexOfWord(all_words, target):
    index = mywords[target]
    for target in range(0, len(mywords)):
        if  target == mywords:
            return(index)
    return(-1)
print(FindIndexOfWord(mywords, "have"))
```

I am pretty sure my mistake is on line 4... but I don't know how to return the position of a word in a list. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try adding `print(target)` in the for loop to see what it's doing.

Comment: See also: [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Do you want to look up value in list by its index or by its value? You need to use different method depending on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Consider using `enumerate(string)` to index a string if you unable to use string methods `find()` or `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making small mistakes.
here is the correct code:

```
bigstring = "I have trouble doing this assignment"
mywords = bigstring.split()
def FindIndexOfWord(all_words, target):
    for i in range(len(mywords)):
        if  target == all_words[i]:
            return i
    return -1
print(FindIndexOfWord(mywords, "this"))
```

Target is a string and not a integer so you can't use

```
index = mywords[target]
```

and return the variable used in looping if string is found else -1

Comment: It makes a lot more sense this way!

Comment: upvote too if it solves your problem. happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find(word)` on the string to get the index of a word.

Comment: I think he's not allowed to, as it's a homework to practice coding (loops and things).

Answer (score 0):

To find the index of a word in alist use `.index()` function and for safety exiting your code when the word is not found use an exception.Shown below:

```
bigstring = "I have trouble doing this assignment"
mywords = bigstring.split()
def FindIndexOfWord(list,word):
    try:
        print(list.index(word))
    except ValueError:
        print(word," not in list.")

FindIndexOfWord(mywords,"have")
```

Output:

```
1
```